# New properties from a second partial class not binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I have a partial class from EntityFramework Called Weights

```
 public partial class Weights
{
    public long WeightID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ClientID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SiteID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DriverID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CarID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Weight1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Weight2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancel { get; set; }
    public bool IsEdit { get; set; }
    public bool IsManual { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTime1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> MaterialID { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    public string Waybill { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Netto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Passage { get; set; }

    public virtual Cars Cars { get; set; }
    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual Drivers Drivers { get; set; }
    public virtual Materials Materials { get; set; }
    public virtual Sites Sites { get; set; }
}
```

now i created another partial Weights Class which i implement INotifyPropertyChanged and add datetimefrom and datetimeto  properties with property change

```
public partial class Weights : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTimeFrom;
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> L_DateTimeFrom
    {
        get { return DateTimeFrom; }
        set
        {
            DateTimeFrom = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeFrom");
        }
    }

    private Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTimeTo;
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> L_DateTimeTo
    {
        get { return DateTimeTo; }
        set
        {
            DateTimeTo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeTo");
        }
    }

    #region "PropertyEvent Change"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

i've created a viewmodel with Weight Filter property also implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class ClosedWeightsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Weights m_filter;
    public Weights Filter
    {
        get { return m_filter; }
        set
        {
            m_filter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter");
        }
    }

    #region "PropertyEvent Change"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

in the xaml i've created 2 datepickers and bind them to datetimefrom/to

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <DatePicker x:Name="dateForm" SelectedDate="{Binding Filter.DateTimeFrom, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dateTo" SelectedDate="{Binding Filter.DateTimeTo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

But it's not binding when i'm selecting a date.
The binding of other properties are working great (CarID,DriverID etc.)

What am i missing?

Comment: property name is `L_DateTimeFrom`, not `DateTimeFrom`. `DateTimeFrom` is *private* and *field*, therefore is not accessible for Binding.  `NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeFrom");` should also be `NotifyPropertyChanged("L_DateTimeFrom");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties are named `L_DateTimeFrom` and `L_DateTimeTo`. You should rename them:

```
private Nullable<System.DateTime> _dateTimeFrom;
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTimeFrom
{
    get { return _dateTimeFrom; }
    set
    {
        _dateTimeFrom = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeFrom");
    }
}

private Nullable<System.DateTime> _dateTimeTo;
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTimeTo
{
    get { return _dateTimeTo; }
    set
    {
        _dateTimeTo = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeTo");
    }
}
```